# Start laravel app on apache2.4 on windows 10

Tags: php, windows, laravel, apache

I have a laravel app, which I test with `php artisan serve`.

I discovered that this is a bad practise, because it is not used on production.

I have installed apache2.4, it worked, when I open localhost I see 'It Works'.

Now I try to start my laravel app through apache on my PC.

For this I have done the following steps:

1. Edited the `httpd.conf` in `Apache\conf`, I uncommented this line:

`LoadModule rewrite_module modules/mod_rewrite.so`

2. Edited the `httpd-vhosts.conf` in `Apache\conf\extra`, I added:

```
<VirtualHost *:80>
    DocumentRoot "Y:/PHP-Projects"
    ServerName localhost 
</VirtualHost>

<VirtualHost *:80>
    DocumentRoot "Y:/PHP-Projects/Project-Admin-PHP/public"
    ServerName localhost.eu 
</VirtualHost>
```

3. Edited the `hosts` file in `Windows\System32\drivers\etc`, I added:

`127.0.0.1 www.localhost.eu localhost.eu`

After every step I restarted the Apache2.4 service, but I still cant access my laravel application. The only thing, what changed is that I now get '**It Works**' also on this domain: `localhost.eu`

What have I missed?

Currently I am starting my laravel app through `php artisan serve`. I can then access the app at `localhost:8000`.

Also I know I could set up homestead. But I discovered it too late. I have already configured and installed everything myself, and besides this one issue, everything works.

I'd like to understand how I would connect my laravel app to the apache server correctly myself.

Comment: Why do you want to run application such like that in localhost...as if you are running application on localhost you should use ```artisan``` command line

Comment: Artisan is slow and f.e. it cant handle parallel AJAX requests, so they stall. I want a realistic environment on localhost. I will use apache on the live server.

Comment: @RajatSharma `artisan` uses the built-in php development server and although the php server and apache try to do the same thing, apache is a complete web server while the php server is only meant for debugging, etc. So to see if your application runs correctly you should always use a real web server.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Probably you forgot include file  `httpd-vhosts.conf` file in `httpd.conf`. Sometimes this line commented by default and you should uncomment this line. After then you should restart apache2 service.

Comment: Awesome, works now. I have a new error `You don't have permission to access / on this server.` But at least it looks like it tries to access my laravel app now. Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

Add server alias on your file config

```
<VirtualHost *:80>
    DocumentRoot "Y:/PHP-Projects/Project-Admin-PHP/public"
    ServerName localhost.eu
    ServerAlias www.localcost.eu
</VirtualHost>
```

Comment: Sadly nothing changed, I still get only 'It Works'